# Terminal scrolling deletes previous output history

Tags: macos, terminal

On macOS Catalina, When I scroll up on a man page (or anything else that fills the screen) blank space appears instead of the text that was shown previously

How can I configure it to show the previous text instead of blankness?

[image: Man page for "man man" after scrolled up]

Comment: How do you scroll up?

Comment: What happens if you hold `Fn` or `Shift` while scrolling?  Does it work properly?

Comment: When you say output history you mean everything that had been written to screen?  Results for" ls -lrt" and "du" for example?  You are using zsh instead of bash, right.  Have you tried iTerm2 instead of terminal?

Comment: i am using bash. It does not work when holding `Fn` or `shift`. I can scroll up, but it does not show the previous output, it is just blank

Comment: @jmh I get the same results after changing to zsh

Comment: @jmh iterm does not have the problem

Comment: @nohillside i scroll up using the 2 finger trackpad scroll

the arrow keys work fine for Man Pages, but in other things (such as screen) they will scroll through commands instead of scrolling up the window

Comment: The reason why scrolling when running screen won't display previous ouput but will scroll through commands is because Terminal sends your input to screen, which interprets it as if you were pressing arrow keys. This behavior is is related to how Terminal deals with so-called "alternate screen scrolling", see https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/display-or-hide-the-alternate-screen-trmld1f46097/mac for details. You can change this behavior with "Scroll alternate screen" in Preferences>Profiles>Keyboard. Note that pressing `Fn` or `Shift` while scrolling will always scroll the view.

Comment: As for why you see a blank screen when scrolling up, some commands like `man` scroll down a whole screen before writing output to the screen, so scrolling up will first display a blank screen.

Comment: turns out that the scrolling up hiding output was a problem with the device that i was SSHing into, and not the Mac terminal. @Allan the `shift` solved the problem

Comment: I found a solution: using the "copy" mode in screen.